# Usar no-ip en servidor y cliente

Tags: python

He hecho una aplicacion cliente _ servidor en python. Pero cuando por ejemplo apago el router la ip ya no me sirve. Necesito saber como implementar no-ip en mi servidor y cliente programados en python y saber si es posible, ya que para conectar mis clientes(pc que tengo en mi casa) necesito que sea una ip estatica. Me recomendaron no-ip pero no se implementarlo en python.

Answer (score 0):

Para actualizar no-ip, tienes que hacer una solicitud, llamada *request* a la interface de programación (API por sus siglas en inglés).

Esta es la documentación de la API: http://www.noip.com/integrate/request

También puedes usar el paquete `npipy` de python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/noipy/1.4.4

Comment: podria hacer un script para que mi pc(cliente) se conectase al dns de mi otro ordenador, si es posible porfavor hazmelo saber gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Claro que podrías, pero eso no tiene que ver con no-ip. El hecho de que uses noip tanto en el cliente como en el servidor, alivia el problema de las ip dinámicas.

Comment: es que como tengo que hacer que se conecten por medio de internet por eso necesito no-ip ademas que mi ip son dinamicas. por eso necesito usar no-ip tanto en mi cliente para que se conecte como en mi servidor